# Problem creating a div container with pictures scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, html, scrollable

i created a div made it scrollable with `<p>text</p>` as seen below:
the code has 2 scrollable buttons that change color once they scrolled all the way to the end.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
#scroller
{
border: 1px solid black;
height: 80px;
width: 400px;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
a
{
display:block;
padding:10px;
background-color:red;
width:25px;
position:relative;
top:20px;
}
div
{
float:left;
}
#type
{
position:absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 250px
}
#left
{
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var PixelPerInterval = 1;
var stop = false;
var t;
var scroll_width;
function scroll_left()
{
document.getElementById('right').style.backgroundColor='red';
document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft-=PixelPerInterval;
if(!stop)
t = setTimeout("scroll_left()",10);
else
stop = false;
scrX = document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft;
divwidth=document.getElementById('scroller').clientWidth;
pwidth=document.getElementById('cont').clientWidth;
type.innerHTML = scrX;
if ((scrX) <= 0)
//type.innerHTML = scrX + ' left';
document.getElementById('left').style.backgroundColor='blue';
}
function scroll_right()
{
document.getElementById('left').style.backgroundColor='red';
document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft+=PixelPerInterval;
if(!stop)
t = setTimeout("scroll_right()",10);
else
stop = false;
scrX = document.getElementById('scroller').scrollLeft;
divwidth=document.getElementById('scroller').clientWidth;
pwidth=document.getElementById('cont').clientWidth;
type.innerHTML = scrX;
if ((divwidth+scrX) >= pwidth)
//type.innerHTML = scrX + ' right';
document.getElementById('right').style.backgroundColor='blue';
}
function stop_scroll() {
stop = true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><a id="left" onmouseover="scroll_left();" onmouseout="stop_scroll();" href="#">Left</a></div>
<div id="scroller">
<p id="cont" style="width:700px;">
alot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of text<br/>
alot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of text<br/>
alot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of text<br/>
alot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of text<br/>
alot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of textalot of text<br/>
</p>
</div>
<div><a id="right" onmouseover="scroll_right();" onmouseout="stop_scroll();" href="#">Right</a></div>
<p id="type">asd</p>
</body>
```

when adding pictures they won't overflow to the right and only down.
thanks alot for the help.

Comment: What speaks against creating a scrollable div only with css?

Comment: Isn't that using CSS3? <br/> i can't use CSS3 and if it isn't in css3 then i have no idea how to scroll using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer related to your comment of doing it purely in CSS, it's NOT CSS 3, just CSS 2.1
Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://whatscookingmexico.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/pear1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://whatscookingmexico.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/pear1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://whatscookingmexico.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/pear1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdJ6r/2/

Comment: Thank you verry much. :) (btw the js i use is only for the scroll bar, i thought u ment also auto scroll using css).

Comment: indead CSS cannot do any autoscroll. But perhaps a little JS that once every so many milliseconds changes the negative margin `#container` could be enough to make that happen. Do change `#wrapper` `overflow: auto;` into `overflow: hidden` then. So the scrollbar doesn't show. Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/pdJ6r/4/ Change the negative margin on #container to see it shift to the left. If you change this by JS, it looks like it is autoscrolling.